# Why the first line of my program is # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I never write it, but now, when I open the script there is the first line:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-.
```

What's that? Why if I never wrote it there is something like that?

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Something is inserting an explicit character encoding for you.

Comment: Sounds like some clever person has rigged your editor to add that line automatically for you on the grounds you must want it because they do.

Comment: IDLE writes it on Windows when using Python 2.x because this is the most common encoding for this OS.

Although UTF-8 would be better.

Comment: It must be a secret what you mean with "open the script". Especially into which program you open it...

Answer (score 7):

I'd assume that your IDE inserted it when saving the file. It's the [file encoding](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for your source file.

Comment: so it's like the #!usr/bin/python?

Comment: No, that specifies the program used to run your script. The file encoding is how your file is encoded on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are file contains some special non ASCII character like "®" then ide will add this line at the starting of your file. If you remove that line from the starting of file then non ASCII character wont be recognized.